# GET http://localhost:8100/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found) with ionic ans Rest Api

Tags: rest, http, ionic-framework

I am creating an application with Ionic framework and rest api but i get a 404 because of headers, I put below some code if you have any solutions I'm listening to you.

Thanks in advance.

```
$http.get({
      url: url,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Context: 'instance='+instance+';token='+token+';user='+userId
      }
  })
  .success(function(reponse){
    console.log(response);
    //$scope.id = data.id;
    $scope.firstName = reponse.user.firstName;
    $scope.lastName = reponse.user.lastName;
    $scope.profession = reponse.user.mission;

    userId = reponse.user.id;
    localStorage.setItem("userId", JSON.stringify(userId));
    $location.path('app/home/');
  }).error(function(reponse, status){
    console.log(reponse + "-" + status);
    alert(status);
});
```

Comment: This is because, the variable **url** is an object. It should be an string. Check on that. A

Comment: Also, if you want to send the url object, use JSON.stringify

Comment: $http.get({
      url: url,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Context: 'instance='+instance+';token='+token+';user='+userId
      }
  })  change this to this  **'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Context': 'instance='+instance+';token='+token+';user='+userId**

Comment: I tried your answer but it does not work